# 6x6 "Landscaping" post for patio cover support?

Tags: structural, patio, post, support

I am building a patio cover and I need some 6x6 posts to support it. I went to a local lumber yard and asked for some 6x6 treated posts. He had some "landscaping" 6x6 posts and said those should work fine.  Is that really ok or should I go somewhere else?

Comment: Most people would not use treated posts for thee vertical supports. The chemicals used to treat are not considered safe for human contact, especially children.

Comment: "Landscaping" refers to their being treated for outdoor use (insect resistant, some treatment also slows rot from ground contact).  But quality varies.  At HD, you may find timbers that are dirt-cheap because they aren't suitable for much other than laying on the ground.  They may be seriously cracked, twisted, or warped, or will become that way when they dry out.  You may need to go to a lumber yard to get better quality timbers to use for posts.  Treated timber is often wet and won't take paint until it dries out, but it should be sealed if children will have a lot of contact with it.

Comment: Are they incised? (Little marks that look like staples all over the face of the 6x6’s.) If so, are they incised on all 4 sides? What color are the posts?

Comment: Lee, they are incised on all four sides and it is reddish in color.